# Why 4th degree polynomials aren't used for trajectory generation?

Tags: trajectory

I'm building and programming a controller for a robotic manipulator. Currently I'm figuring out how to generate trajectories in joint space. I'm following *Introduction to Robotics: Analysis, Control, Applications* by Saeed B. Niku and while he talks about using the 3rd and 5th polynomial, he skips over the 4th. [Northwestern](https://modernrobotics.northwestern.edu/nu-gm-book-resource/9-1-and-9-2-point-to-point-trajectories-part-2-of-2/) also skips it and *Introduction to Robotics: Mechanics and Control* by John J. Craig only mentions 3rd. *Robot Manipulators: Mathematics, Programming, and Control* by Richard P. Paul actually mentions it (p. 135 above eq. 5.38), saying that it will be used as the symmetry allows that the 5th degree polynomial does't have to be used. However I don't fully get that book.

Given that higher order polynomials require more calculations and the 4th degree polynomial is the first which doesn't produce any sudden changes in acceleration, why isn't it used as the best option?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Radar, but I'm afraid that questions which are as underspecified and based on an unsupported assumption as this are off topic. Your question is based off of assumptions from your research which we can't see or comment on. As it says in [ask] we prefer *[answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so please take a look at [ask], [about] and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for advice on writing a good question.